# Powershell Invoke-Response Where Clause

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script that runs without issue. I am being told that I need to add "`&onlyCurrent=false`" to get it to pull information for employees with a future start date. I have no idea how to do this....

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api._________.com/api/gateway.php/gemco/v1/reports/120' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

When I add this to the end, I get invalid parameter error message:
-Where-Object onlyCurrent eq "false"

The support for they system I'm pulling this from has no information on how to do this. Absolutely any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`&onlyCurrent=false` is probably a query string. You can append it at the end of the URL after `?`. Note that `&` is used to separate multiple parameters, since you have just one it's not needed. Try changing the URL to:

`https://api._________.com/api/gateway.php/gemco/v1/reports/120?onlyCurrent=false`

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. You have to add ?onlyCurrent=false after the 120 (inside the single quote).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).